# Encoding a large unsigned integer as a fixed length (256bit) unsigned data

Tags: javascript

I have a large unsigned integer (close to but less than 256bit). I have the integer as BigInt.

I want to encode it as 256bit fixed length binary and convert it base64.
(also decode it later)

```
unsinged int (BigInt) -> 256 bit binary -> base64 (String) -> unsigned int
```

Is there a good way to do it?

Comment: Is the integer in base 10?

Comment: What representation are you currently using?

Comment: The input unsigned integer is in BigInt format.

Answer (score 0):

Well, [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) really helps with this..

look at the snippet below

```js
function encode(int,encoding=256,signed){
  if(typeof encoding!=="number"){encoding=parseInt( encoding.toString() )}
  if(signed){encoding--} //signed integers use the first bit as + or -
  let size=2n**BigInt(encoding), filling="", sign=""
  if(typeof int!=="bigint"){int=BigInt(int)}
  
  //determining the binary string value
  let negative=int.toString()[0]==="-"
  let num=negative? -1n*(int%size): (int%size) //a positive number less than size
  signed?(negative?sign=1:sign=0):null //determining sign(or doing nothing if not signed)
  let value=(  negative&&!signed? (size-num): num  ).toString(2)
  
  //to fill the spaces of empty bits
  let length=encoding-value.length
  for(let i=0;i<length;i++){filling+=0}
  
  return btoa(sign+filling+value) //returns a base64 String of 1s and 0s representing a binary encoded number
}

function decode(string,signed){ //returns a BigInt of the encoded string's value
  string=atob(string)
  return signed?
  -1n*BigInt("0b"+string.substr(1)): //the signed translation
  BigInt("0b"+string) //the unsigned translation
}

console.log(encode(42)) //unsigned binary 256 bit of normal number
console.log(encode(4213213283721893738293789312731893n)) //unsigned binary 256 bit of a BigInt
console.log(encode("21157920892373161954235709850086879078532699846656405640394575840079131296399362")) //unsigned binary 256 bit of number larger than 2**256
console.log(encode("-21157920892373161954235709850086879078532699846656405640394575840079131296399362",128)) //unsigned binary 128 bit of number larger than 2**128
console.log(encode("-21157920892373161954235709850086879078532699846656405640394575840079131296399362",128,true)) //signed binary 128 bit of number larger than 2**128

console.log(decode( //unsigned encoded string DECODED
  encode(4213213283721893738293789312731893n)
))
console.log(decode( //signed encoded string DECODED
  encode(-4213213283721893738293789312731893n,256,true),true
))
```

In case the StackOverflow's `console.log` didn't show the full results, here's a screenshot: [image: base64 strings of binary integers]

Comment: thanks, but I want to convert the fixed length binary to Base64, and also decode it.

Comment: @ywat do you mean like this edit?